# My BST function to find maximum element of left subtree and minimum element of right subtree wont return values

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

This is my function to return maximum element of left subtree and  minimum element of right subtree

```
def Max(root):#this will return maximum element of left subtree
    if  root.left and not root.right:
        return root.data
    if root.right:
        Max(root.right)
    else:
        Max(root.left)
def Min(root):#this will return minimum element of right subtree
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        return root.data
    if root.left:
        Min(root.left)
    else:
        Min(root.right)
def InorderPreSuc(root):
    pre=Max(root.left)
    suc=Min(root.right)
    print(' predecessor {} and successor {}.format(pre,suc))
```

But my function wont return the values Why?

Answer (score 2):

Maximum of left subtree would be finding the max at root.left, similarly minimum of right subtree would be the min of root.right

To recursively find min or max:

```
# Max of a BST would be its rightmost element
def Max(root):
    if root.right is not None:
        Max(root.right)
    return root.data

# Min of BST would be its leftmost element
def Min(root):
    if root.left is not None:
        Min(root.left)
    return root.data
```

Now to find maximum of left subtree call Max(root.left).
We can add another check for null value in case the root is null.

```
def Min(root):
    if root is None:
        return float("-inf")
    if root.left is not None:
        Min(root.left)
    return root.data
```

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with my code cause if i use a print statement inside the function the required output is obtained but it doesnt return the value what i mean is if i print root.data inside the max and min function i get the output but it is not returned by the function

Comment: Given my implementation, there is no difference whether you print or return the value. The function recursively traverses to the leftmost (or rightmost child) - which gives us the node with the minimum (or maximum) value containing node. You can then do whatever you wish with that node - print it, return it, swap it, increment/decrement it. The important part is to traverse to the leftmost or rightmost child to get the desired node.